# The page isn't redirecting properly in drupal error

Tags: redirect, drupal

### 1) Here is the message displaying on my page when I Open the page

The page isn't redirecting properly
firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.

Answer (score -1):

Probably you have some kind of circular re directions, like, first page is redirecting to second and second back to first. That way redirecting enters in endless loop.